# QPSK Channel Detection Algorithm

Tags: qpsk, channel, channel-estimation

I send a QPSK signal over pluto sdr and receive it from rtlsdr. As you can see from the screenshot below SNR of the received signal is very high, and the signal is very distinguishable. Hence, it is very easy to find carrier frequency and bandwidth of the signal by monitoring the spectrum. I wonder if there is a robust algorithm that detects existence of any QPSK signal and estimate it's basic parameters such as carrier frequency and bandwidth. Note that I am assuming there is no non-QPSK channel in the spectrum.

The simple idea I can think of is to track the value of each FFT bin, then mark the bin if it exceeds certain power threshold (-70 dB can be selected for the signal below). I also assume that the minimum bandwidth of any QPSK signal is 50 kHz. If there is any **continuous** marked bins which is larger than the 50 kHz, then the algorithm decides there is a QPSK channel. Besides, the algorithm estimates bandwidth as width of the marked bins, and center frequency by calculating center point of these continuous bins. However, I don't know how to select power threshold especially when there are multiple QPSK channels with different SNRs.

Do you know any robust algorithm that solves my problem?

[image: QPSK Waterfall]

Comment: Search for "automatic modulation detection". There are many papers and at least a couple of books on the subject.

Comment: Actually, my goal is not to detect modulation type but only detect the existence of channel, center frequency and bandwidth of that channel. Also, I know that all channels will be QPSK.

Comment: Actually, some AMD methods detect not only the modulation type but also the bandwidth. Another related area is "spectrum sensing"; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_radio.